# Has anyone built a recurring events UI for jquery full calendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I see that [jquery full calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) supports recurring events by having the multiple events having the same I'd but I am surprised that there isn't any UI component to go along with it.  Is there any UI component that anyone has built for this. (similar to the outlook UI)

I am trying to avoid building from scratch given it seems like a generic component.  My backend is asp.net-mvc but I guess that shouldn't really matter

it would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, except I'm using php?

Comment: Seems generic, but in order to be truly generic, it would have to handle a large number of calendars world-wide (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars). That said, I've written a similar UI at least twice ;)

Comment: I'm confused, do you have recurring events you need to display? If so, how is the information being stored?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=116 see if this link helps

Comment: my suggestion would be whatever way you are using to enter the events with date time location and all use the same element for getting input recurring event information and then at the event

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Are you trying a build a scheduler? See this link here - http://www.cronmaker.com/.

Comment: @leora .... could you build the recurrence stuff with fullcalendar? i'm trying to build the same stuff for a clinic which have patients with long treatments (recurrent events)...

Answer (score 7):

I recommend this plugin - it was helpful to me.

[https://github.com/collective/jquery.**recurrenceinput**.js](https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js)

Answer (score 2):

Check this one

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jqeventcalendar/

wdCalendar is a javascript event calendar, which is like google calendar

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use it with Google Calendar as the frontend?

Comment: because i am trying to embed inside my website

Comment: You can embed Google Calendar on your website. Also of note is Google Apps

Comment: Very late comment, but I tried to go down this route for a project, and Google only allows but a relatively stripped down, read-only version of a calendar to be embedded. They respond with a X-Frame-Options header to disable embedding of the full UI on calendar.google.com.