# Recurrence Picker in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I am developing a mobile app using ionic framework. I am looking for a Recurrence Picker without jQuery and bootstrap dependencies in AngularJS
just like Google Calendar that I attached.

[image]

Is there any Recurrence picker plugin in AngularJS?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Is there any Recurrence picker plugin in AngularJS?

Comment: hm. It would indeed be nice to have a ui that could build iCal recurrence rule strings. This thing can parse them: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Comment: ui-calender has bootstrap dependencies which is not desirable in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options I found while I was in the exact situation as the OP:

https://github.com/devmynd/angular_rrule_recurring_select

https://github.com/chouseknecht/angular-scheduler

https://github.com/jacobscarter/angular-cron-jobs

If you're using Angular UI Calendar which is currently dependent on jQuery anyways you could roll your own hybrid directive with the jQuery plugins that are out there:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11607742/1742393

I will probably just end up making a custom one.

Edit: I ended up creating a custom directive that allows the user to enter plain text that is parsed by [rrule.js](http://jkbrzt.github.io/rrule/).

Answer (score 0):

There is [this](https://github.com/devmynd/angular_rrule_recurring_select) one, which uses the [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) library.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried both from above but they don't build so I was not able to evaluate the UI.

https://github.com/devmynd/angular_rrule_recurring_select

https://github.com/chouseknecht/angular-scheduler

After being frustrated, I found `ac-recurrence` on npm which is a plus. I've integrated with my code base with minimal changes for my build system. The UI looks okay but do plan to style it a bit differently.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ac-recurrence

[image]